# o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper : ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = bytea

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am using hibernate-core:jar:5.3.10 in the spring project. I have table company_interview_levels which has one to many relation from the Company table. and when I am trying call findByIvLevelAndCompanyId it is throwing an exception. The whole stack track mention below.

Here is the model class for company_interview_levels

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPANY_INTERVIEW_LEVELS")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonFilter("CompanyInterviewLevels")
public class CompanyInterviewLevels implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6868521896546285046L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="IV_LEVEL")
    private String ivLevel;

    @Column(name="COMPANY_ID")
    private Company companyId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "CREATED_ON")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdOn = new Date();

    @Column(name = "CREATED_BY")
    private User createdBy;
}
```

Here is the repository interface

```
@Repository
public interface CompanyInterviewLevelsRepository  extends JpaRepository<CompanyInterviewLevels, Long>
{
    List<CompanyInterviewLevels> findByCompanyId(Company company);

    @Transactional
    CompanyInterviewLevels findByIvLevelAndCompanyId(String ivLevel, Company companyId);

    @Transactional
    void deleteByIvLevelAndCompanyId(String ivLevel, Company company);
}
```

Exception

```
Hibernate: select companyint0_.id as id1_26_, companyint0_.company_id as company_2_26_, companyint0_.created_by as created_3_26_, companyint0_.created_on as created_4_26_, companyint0_.iv_level as iv_level5_26_ from company_interview_levels companyint0_ where companyint0_.iv_level=? and companyint0_.company_id=?
2021-07-27 20:39:35.190 ERROR [o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper 142] 222694 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 302
2021-07-27 20:39:35.206 ERROR [o.a.j.l.DirectJDKLog 175] 222694 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 302
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:106) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2167) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1930) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1508) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1553) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:221) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:138) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy156.findByIvLevelAndCompanyId(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at io.litmusblox.server.service.impl.CompanyService.lambda$addDeleteInterviewLevels$13(CompanyService.java:966) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at io.litmusblox.server.service.impl.CompanyService.addDeleteInterviewLevels(CompanyService.java:965) ~[classes/:na]
    at io.litmusblox.server.service.impl.CompanyService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c595e541.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:684) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at io.litmusblox.server.service.impl.CompanyService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$140429fc.addDeleteInterviewLevels(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at io.litmusblox.server.controller.CompanyDataController.addDeleteInterviewLevels(CompanyDataController.java:304) ~[classes/:na]
    at io.litmusblox.server.controller.CompanyDataController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d84fd37d.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:684) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at io.litmusblox.server.controller.CompanyDataController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$40174cd6.addDeleteInterviewLevels(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at io.litmusblox.server.security.LbAuthRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(LbAuthRequestFilter.java:101) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entity mapping is wrong. You need to map your associations with `@ManyToOne`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPANY_INTERVIEW_LEVELS")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonFilter("CompanyInterviewLevels")
public class CompanyInterviewLevels implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6868521896546285046L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="IV_LEVEL")
    private String ivLevel;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="COMPANY_ID")
    private Company companyId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "CREATED_ON")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdOn = new Date();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CREATED_BY")
    private User createdBy;
}
```